# Using params in $http GET request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, service, get, parameters

I put a $http request into a service. However, it should retrieve the data depending on the users input to a form. the url attribute defines the baseUrl and the params attribute defines the flexibel URL.

```
angular.module('mean.system').service('flightReq',function($http,$location){
    var baseUrl='/system/views/airfareData.json';
    var method='GET';
    var Request={};
    this.flightReq=function(){
        $http({
            method:method,
            url:baseUrl,
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            params: {'dep':'a', 'arr':'b','number':'c', 'date1':'d'},
            cache:true
        })
        .success(function(data,status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            $location.path('/resultpresentation/example');
            Request=data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log(data||"Request failed");
            $location.path('/');
        });

        };
    this.getRequest=function(){
        return Request
    };
});
```

As you can see, params is defined fixed to 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'. But I want it to be flexibel depending on the user's input. How would I do this?

If the $http request would be a controller and not a service I could simply do $scope.dep etc. However, I don't know how to do it in this case. Any suggestions? Cheers

Comment: Just pass in an object containing the params to your $http call.

Comment: You mean, I should pass in an object that I obtain from the controller (where I store the input of the user)? How  would I do that?

Comment: just pass a `$scope.yourModelWithUserInput` as argument to service and then use the argument as params

Comment: sorry,  I seem to be a little confused. I named all input field ng-model="formData.dep" ng-model="formData.arr" etc and defined $scope.formData={}. So every input is instantly stored into formData. If I now inject formData into my service I will obtain an error: Unknown provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject your service into your controller:

```
.controller('someNameCtrl', ['$scope', 'flightReq', function($scope, flightReq) {

}
```

Then from the controller, you'll pass the scope as arguments to the service

```
.controller('someNameCtrl', ['$scope', 'flightReq', function($scope, flightReq) {
 ...
    flightReq.flightReq($scope.formData.dep,$scope.formData.arr,$scope.formaData.number,$scope.formData.date1);
 ... 
}
```

Your service will take those arguments and use them as the params:

```
angular.module('mean.system').service('flightReq',function($http,$location){
   var baseUrl='/system/views/airfareData.json';
   var method='GET';
   var Request={};
   this.flightReq=function(dep,arr,number,date1){
    $http({
        method:method,
        url:baseUrl,
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        params: {'dep': dep, 'arr': arr,'number': number, 'date1': date1},
        cache:true
    })
```